# when i run pip from cmd on python 3.9 i just installed on windows 10, it gives a wierd error and stops

Tags: python, pip

when I try to use pip from cmd, it does this:

```
C:\Users\user1>python -m pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-noqt88le\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-noqt88le\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-xj2gjez_'
         cwd: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-noqt88le\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-noqt88le\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-noqt88le\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-noqt88le\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-noqt88le\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it, I don't even know what it means!! thanks so much!

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3884), you should be able to solve it by just:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Months ago I encountered the same problem, and I "solved" by using *virtual environments*, which can be created using

```
python -m venv {NAME OF ENVIRONMENT}
```

The virtual env will act like a new python installation - so installing it again should also solve your problem.

Good luck! Anything we are here.